# Virgin Media search (Enhanced by Google) not returning website

Tags: seo, search-results

I have made a website for a client and worked very hard on the SEO for Google and Bing. The site is now being returned on the first page for both.

The client found a strange issue as he uses http://www.virginmedia.com/ as his homepage, which comes with its very own search bar that is "Enhanced by Google".

No matter what keywords you put in the search, the site is not being shown in the results. I have tried and tested this vigorously, I have made sure that the 'Web' option is picked as they have options for 'This Website' too.

I have looked to see if Virgin Media have a similar thing to Webmaster tools to submit sitemap etc but can't find anything.

Has anyone else had this issue or found a fix?

Comment: Sadly, there's nothing to fix. The search engines offered by BT, SKY, Virgin Media have different results than those generally found on google.co.uk and google.com, this is because they follow a modified algorithm, and even more often the results are slower to take, for example a new site takes longer to get listed on Google custom search engines, sites hit by negative SEO also takes longer to take effect. So, if its new site then you just need to wait longer.

Comment: Thank's Simon. I did think or hope this was the answer. The site is being returned on Google, Bing and Yahoo so all the usual suspects have been covered. Just have to wait and see. Thanks Again. :)